# iOS How to show 12 hour time format if user set 24 hour time in system without changing locale to specific identifier

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nslocale

My question is how to show 12 hour time format in app, if user's system setting is 24 hour time. I don't want to change dateFromatter.locale to a specific one.

My research is:

If system setting using 12 Hour, format `"HH"` will show 24H and `"hh"` will show 12H.

However, if system setting using 24H, both format `"HH"` and `"hh"` will show 24H, and `"a"` is ignored.

Seems like 24H system setting is overriding format string in app.

I've known `NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")` will show 12H and `NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB")` will show 24H. However, changing locale of NSDateFormatter will result in fixed time string in other language such as Chinese and Japanese

Comment: What is the full date/time format you want to use? Why do you want to force 12-hour format when the user prefers 24-hour?

Comment: @maddy 12H format is "hh:mm a", 24H is "HH:mm". No I'm not forcing 12H format, I just want to provide a time setting option in app. User can use different time format disregard of use's global system setting

Comment: Why don't you want to use a locale id. Think it'd the only way in this situation

Comment: @Remover Since this will ignore user's locale settings, which is not what I want. I just want to change 12/24 format, whiteout changing their language or something.

Comment: Can you not just a different formatter for other bits that you want localised? You should be able to set calendars etc on the formatter to ensure the dates of times are locale specific. You'd think so anyway.

Comment: @HonghaoZhang I know that his an old topic but did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @sliwinski.lukas I just hacked with `en_US_POSIX` locale and `en_GB` locale for explicitly showing the 12H format. This is a little ugly, but it works for now.